# spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames not working on Master Page

Tags: javascript, spbodyonload

we are trying to execute some script after the master page loads.

```
 <script language="javascript">  
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FunctionName");   
        function FunctionName()   
        {   
           alert('test');
        }   
    </script>  
</head>
```

We are not getting the alert. Any thing missing here? Tried to debug in IE, the debugger does not get hit. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure the script is actually there in the emitted html?

Answer (score 1):

You need `init.js` loaded before `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` can work, make sure its loaded before running your script. `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` is an array, that are execute in the `ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames` function. The `ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames` is executed in the `ProcessDefaultOnLoad` function. The `ProcessDefaultOnLoad` is execute with: `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ProcessDefaultOnLoad, "core.js");`

You could also use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(FunctionName());` or `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(FunctionName, "core.js");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of at the top in the head, put it in a `script` tag at the bottom of the page.

Comment: should'nt javascript script tags always be in the head?, just asking. Im new to this. Where exactly in  the bottom? (right at end of amsterpage?) or before /body?