# How can I ScrollTop in SharePoint 2010 with JQuery

Tags: 2010, jquery, sharepoint-server

I try to scroll the SharePoint page after the page loaded.

Using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#WebPartWPQ1').offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

It starts scrolling the page, he problem is, that it scrolls back immediately.

Please help, how can I set in SharePoint 2010 not to scroll back after the page is loaded?

EDIT: I found the following code [here](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/28/fix-disabled-page-scrolling-on-navigation-settings/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[action="AreaNavigationSettings.aspx"]')
        .closest('body')
        .css('overflow', 'visible')
        .find('#s4-workspace')
        .css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

which removes the scrollbar from the right of '#s4-workspace', I am wondering how this code could be modified not to remove scrollbar, but scroll to position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, Tiago, thanks again for the suggestions!

The solution was much closer I expected.

It seems that after `$(document).ready` there are still scripts running which overwrite executed commands.

This I could find out using the above code in the "EDIT:" part of my comment:

```
    $('form[action="AreaNavigationSettings.aspx"]')
    .closest('body')
    .css('overflow', 'visible');
```

The snippet added back the scrollbar for the whole page, however, only momentarily.

Searching then for

"how to execute jQuery after all $(document).ready() done"

I found

"use $(window).load(), which fires after $(document).ready()"

With this Even Paul's code works like charm

Comment: I think you should be using SharePoint's built in functions that allow you to add a callback to be executed after the page loads... If you are messing with window.load() then you are also messing with SHarepoint's load functions - which are bound to the load events... 
Some of the methods can be found here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93937/spbodyonloadfunctionnames-not-working-on-master-page
Also: Is this really the solution to your original problem? How did you ultimately fix the problem of scrolling to a given element?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how your code is working - unless you have a very customized version of the Master page... In SharePoint >= 2010, the "body" of the page (area below the ribbon that has a scroll bar) is actually a `<div>` with an id of *s4-workspace*... Try this:

```
$("#s4-workspace").animate({scrollTop: $('#WebPartWPQ1').offset().top}, 1000);
```

The above code works for me on SP2013 from the console...

If it is still scrolling back, then maybe add a setTimeout() with about 100ms dealy... something else is trying to get focus and thus the page is jumping...

Comment: The first code scrolls at least - just scrolls back, this second code does not scroll at all.

Comment: +1 the code from @Paul works fine provided that you are using the ootb master page, jquery is loaded, and you are doing that on document ready. no delay required. now, if you are using custom branding, that's another problem

Comment: ootb master - ok;  
jquery - loaded, the first working version validates;  
document ready - same code used as the first, with the second animate java code

Comment: I can't understand how _$('html, body').animate()_ can be working. the OOB master page and the content of the page is not placed inside of the body tag... its inserted into an element with id of _s4-workspace_. I doubt you are using an OOB page or maybe there is something else on the page that has forced/inserted items into the body tag.  Can you post the html markup of the page somewhere?  Also, when you say that the code on your initial post works: is the Ribbon still accessible? do you get scroll bars on the browser window that spans entire height of the window - or only below the ribbon?

Comment: This is an OOB page, the ribbon still accessible, and scroll bar only show up under the ribbon. It seems to be some off-frame scrolling hence it rolls back once code executed.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Unless I can see the HTML markup, there is not much I can do. Good lick finding a solution

Comment: newuser's code animates and then immediately jumps into the top. I managed to reproduce the same behaviour. @paul's code is working for me, but not for the user, apparently, which may lead to custom stuff running on his side

Comment: Thanks for checking @tiago. This is puzzling to me. So you were able to place a webpart outside of the s4-workspace div?

Comment: the webpart im using is inside the main area.

Comment: Could this be as this I would set on a publishing site page, and not the main page? In the source I see right after the <body> tag: <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="/MySite/MySitePublishingPage.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">